# How to use javascript rxjs to run batches of calculations

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, rxjs

I am new to rxjs, but need to use this asynchronous regime to fulfill such task:
I have many calculation requests, say 10K, and I want to execute them in batches: 1K per batch and the batch is pre-determined. Only when the current batch is done, I will move on to the next batch. The function will be:
calcBatch(dataset)
The input dateset will come from an array of datasets: datasets = [...]
the synchronous loop would look like:

```
datasets.foreach(dataset=> {
   while (!calculation_is_done) {
      wait();
   }
   calcBatch(dataset);
});

calcBatch(dataset) {
   calculation_is_done = false;
   /* calculation */
   calculation_is_done = true;
}
```

Now switching to an asynchronous regime, how should I construct the flow? What I am thinking is in the calcBatch, when the work is done, a promise or an observable will be returned. Then in the loop, a subscriber will listen on this promise or observable, once it is caught, calcBatch will be called for the next batch.

The calculation needs to process in batches because the backend (HTTP) cannot handle a full set of calculation.

Comment: When you say **asynchronous regime** do you mean, for instance, that `calcBatch` is a function that calls an http Rest service which performs the calculations and returns asynchronously the result by invoking some sort of callback function you pass to it?

Comment: Correct, calcBatch itself is also an asynchronous function which will rely on http rest service. I can make sure that when calcBatch is done, a flag will be turned on. So an observable is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `bufferCount` and `concatMap` might be what you need:

```js
function calcBatch(dataset) {
  console.log('Processing batch:', dataset)

  // Fake async request
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(dataset), 2000)
  })
}

from(datasets)
  .pipe(
    bufferCount(1000),
    concatMap(dataset => calcBatch(dataset))
  )
  .subscribe(dataset => {
    console.log('Batch done:', dataset)
  })
```

Note: `calcBatch` needs to return a promise or an observable.

Comment: Thank you. I don't need bufferCount to manage the number of calculation because the division is predetermined.

Comment: @user2355104 so is `datasets` an array of arrays? If so, then `concatMap` should still work for you if you just remove `bufferCount`.